# Copying a section of a vector<UINT16> into a double variable

Tags: c++, std, memcpy

I have a list of objects that have `vector<uint16>`s as members.
These vectors essentially capture a stream of data related to that object.
The data streams range from 16 - 256 bits in length.

Im interested in slicing up portions of that vector into `double` variables.

IE:

```
vector<uint16> data = { 00FA, 78BB, FFFF, 1234, 6C9D, ..., n }
double formatted_data = ( data from spot 0 to spot 3 )
```

Would `memcpy()` or `std::copy()` be the a way to go about this?  Or is there a better way to do this?

To be clear, the originator of the data are also storing the values in doubles, the data I recieve are memory representations of that data.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve with this code? Did you consider about dealing with endianess issues?

Comment: `memcpy()` is the way to go

Comment: The vector holds stream of data that may contain one more size pieces of size double data I am interested in outputting to a user.  I am asking what is the best way to go about copying segments of the vector into Doubles.  *Edit:  In regards to Endianess yes I did which why i am concerned and asked the question.  If there needs to be a rearchitecting the way the data is originally stored i am open to that too"

Comment: Whats is unclear is: what do you want to copy? Is it the memory representation? If yes, follow NathanOliver advice. If not, please [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Are you serializing those objects and sending the data to other machines which may have or not the same endianness of yours or it all stays in the same architecture?

Comment: Yes to be clear the data is a memory representation of captured data from else where.  The data from the originator are also doubles.  Each of the objects in question can either be a single double or an array of doubles. hence why i used a vector to give me flexibility to handle varying sizes

Comment: @Chris Please [edit] your question rather than burying such information in comments. Even better post a [mcve] to illustrate your problem.

Comment: How are the input bits formatted compared with the binary format of a `double`? Not all architectures are necessarily the same.

Comment: Also use `std::copy` over `memcpy` as it is safer and just as fast. Also endianness is easily fixed/allowed for by substituting `std::reverse_copy`.

Comment: @Galik How would you call `std::copy` in this case?

Comment: @NathanOliver That depends on the format in the input but its not hard.

Comment: @Galik Could you show me?  I can't think of a non UB way to call `std::copy` here.

Comment: @NathanOliver What is the format in this case? Is each `16bit` value a whole part of a `double`? Or do `doubles` cross the `16bit` boundaries?

Comment: @Galik The OP wants to combine 4 `uint16_t`'s into a single `double`.

Comment: @NathanOliver `memcpy` copies *as if* by copying one `char` at a time, `std::copy` can do exactly the same albeit explicitly

Comment: @Galik I know that.  I asked how.  How do you convert everything to `char`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188491/discussion-between-galik-and-nathanoliver).

Comment: actually @Galik id like to know too.  would it be like "std::copy(myvec.data(), myvect.data() + 3, &doubleVariable)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal vector member function call data() likely solves your problem here:

```
memcpy(&formatted_data, data.data(), sizeof(double));
```

`std::vector::data()` returns a pointer to the first element in the internally maintained c-style array for the designated vector.